# Java choose txt file and use the string insaid in a function

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, applet

i update the code but it raised a new error in

```
List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
```

the error is :

> error: type List does not take parameters
>            List temps = new LinkedList();

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    if (selectedFile == null) {
    return;  // no file selected. Get out of here
  }
  String token1 = "";
  Scanner inFile1 = null;
  try {
    inFile1 = new Scanner(selectedFile);

     List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();
    // while loop
    while(inFile1.hasNext()){

        // find next line
        token1 = inFile1.next();

        // initialize temps
        temps.add(token1);
    }

    // close inFile1
    inFile1.close();

    // create array
    String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

    // for-each loop
     String  ArabicWord="";
    for(String s : tempsArray){ 

        ArabicWord = ArabicWord + " " + s;

    }
          String finalResult="";
 for (String retval: ArabicWord.split(" ")){
          ArabicStemmer Stemmer=new ArabicStemmer();
         finalResult= finalResult + " " +  String.valueOf(Stemmer.stemWord(retval));
                 }


 jTextArea1.setText(finalResult);



  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }


    }
```

Comment: Right now your question is not really a question but more a list of things you want, and a bit of unexplained code. Please improve it by telling us more, including what problems your current code is experiencing and exactly where you may be stuck.

Comment: i update my Q and the error now in Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(jTextField1.getText()));

Comment: You state, `"but the error in..."` -- please tell us more pertinent details. What errors are you getting? And why not instead of using the JTextField's text, simply store the File itself that you obtain from the JFileChooser, and use that?

Comment: C:\Users\Malek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication1\src\javaapplication1\ArabicStemmerFram.java:120: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
1 error

Comment: the previous comment shows the error what i get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could give my class a File field for the selected file, say called selected file:

```
private File selectedFile = null;
```

And then in the first action listener, assign a value to that field:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
   int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
     selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
     String filename=F.getName();
     jTextField1.setText(filename);
   }
}
```

And then would use the selectedFile in the next bit of code. Java is complaining that you're trying to initialize a Scanner without catching exceptions, and so you should follow the suggestion of the error message: catch your exceptions.

For example:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  if (selectedFile == null) {
    return;  // no file selected. Get out of here
  }
  String token1 = "";
  Scanner inFile1 = null;
  try {
    inFile1 = new Scanner(selectedFile);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
  }

  // .....
```

You most definitely need to read a tutorial or two about how to handle exceptions. Google will help you find these.

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> error: type List does not take parameters List temps = new LinkedList();

I fear that this may be due to your importing `java.awt.*`. If your code has this line:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Delete it, because you're confusing the compiler as to just what type of List you are trying to use. You are trying to use a `java.util.List` but the compiler may be thinking that you're using a `java.awt.List`. The best way to fix this is to import the specific awt classes that you're using and not use the wild card `*` for imports. Sometimes you have to forgo the imports altogether and simply use fully specified class names in your code. For example, sometimes you have to go the route:

```
java.util.List<String> myList = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
```